# How to use CKEditor for Mathematical Formulas with MathJax in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mathjax, ckeditor4.x

**I want to use CKEditor which also creating mathematical formulas with Mathjax.
I am able to use CKEditor without Mathjax. I can not figure out how to use Mathjax Plugin of CKEditor in reactjs. Though I am able to do it in raw code(HTML and Javascript).**

Here is my process to add CKEditor:

**Install the ckeditor4-react:**

```
npm install ckeditor4-react
```

**App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-react';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h2>Using CKEditor 4 in React</h2>
                <CKEditor
                    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 4!</p>"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Now how can I use mathjax plugin of CKEditor? or if there another way?**

Answer (score 0):

working example of CKEditor for mathematical formulas with mathJax in Reactjs.

> CodeSandBox url given at the end. check it.

```
import React from "react";
import CKEditor from "ckeditor4-react";

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: ""
    };
    CKEditor.editorUrl = "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.0/standard-all/ckeditor.js";
  }

  onEditorChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      data: e.editor.getData()
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CKEditor
          data={this.state.data}
          onChange={this.onEditorChange}
          config={{
            extraPlugins: "ckeditor_wiris",
            removePlugins:
              "filetools,uploadimage,uploadwidget,uploadfile,filebrowser,easyimage",
            allowedContent: true
          }}
          onBeforeLoad={(CKEDITOR) => {
            CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal(
              "ckeditor_wiris",
              "/mathtype-ckeditor4/",
              "plugin.js"
            );
          }}
        />

        <div className="editor-preview">
          <h2>Rendered content</h2>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.data }}></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

include scriptTag in `public/index.html` if it's not set in component initial render.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML"></script>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-dawn-8kvrg?file=/src/App.js